# Customizing Symfony 2 form with bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

i have a problem understanding the form component in Symfony 2, first I want to customize my form with some bootstrap classes but the problem is I don't know how, because in the twig template there's only these lines

```
{% extends 'Bundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content -%}
<div class="panel-heading"> <h3>Category</h3></div>
   <div class="panel-body">

       {{ form(edit_form) }}

          <ul class="record_actions">
         <li>
          <a href="{{ path('category') }}">
            Back to the list
          </a>
         </li>
        <li>{{ form(delete_form) }}</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
{% endblock %}
```

for instance I want to change the form to something like this using bootstrap

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Category </div>
      <div class="panel-body"> 
       <form class="form-horizontal">

         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Name" class="control-label col-xs-2"> CategoryName</label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" id="Name" placeholder="Category name" >
            </div>
         </div>



         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
            </div>
         </div>

       </form>
```

Comment: check your form helper

Comment: check `form_div_layout.html.twig` in twig you might edit it there

Comment: And If You dont want to override form functions You can render all parts separately by using `form_` functions http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html

Comment: oki thank you but i don't have time to change twig templates, so i prefer to change only in my own templates because it's easy for me, if there's another documentation please provide it to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is found in the Symfony docs at [Rendering each field manually](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand).  So you want to do something like this for your form then:

```
<div class="panel-body">

   {{ form_start(edit_form  }}

   <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(edit_form.categoryName, 'CategoryName', {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label col-xs-2'}}) }}
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            {{ form_widget(edit_form.categoryName, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}})  }}
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

Or something along these lines. As you can see, you can add classes to the twig rendered forms.  for a complete reference of the twig templating functions, see the docs [Twig Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html)

If you are rendering the button with twig as well, then you could do this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.editButton, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}}) }}
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: the problem is it still give the old edit button before the custom bootstrap edit button

Comment: are you rendering the button from twig as well?  I just added an example to add a class to a button rendered in twig